# Downloading and installing Meteor via Dockerfile

Tags: docker

When [This Dockerfile](https://github.com/popestepheng/meteor-production-docker-example/blob/master/Dockerfile)  is run. It ends with `returned a non-zero code: 1` in the terminal.

The following is printed in red colour:

> Downloading Meteor distribution
>
> Meteor 1.4.1.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
>   Writing a launcher script to /usr/local/bin/meteor for your convenience.
>
> To get started fast:
>
> $ meteor create ~/my_cool_app
>    $ cd ~/my_cool_app
>    $ meteor
>
> Or see the docs at:
>
> docs.meteor.com
>
> Supply the server hostname and port in the --server option for mobile app
>   builds.

followed by the command from line 15 - 39.

What does this mean and How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: To be printed in read does not mean it's an error. It only means that it's printed to the standard error. Please, paste the full output of the `build` command to see where the error is.